# java thread not running even after start call

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TestSynchronization {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadTest[] threads = new ThreadTest[10];
    int i = 0;
    for(Thread th : threads) {
        th = new Thread(Integer.toString(i++));
        th.start();
    }
}

class ThreadTest extends Thread {

    TestSynchronization ts = new TestSynchronization();

    public /*synchronized */void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            ts.testingOneThreadEntry(this);
            System.out.println(new Date());
            System.out.println("Hey! I just came out and it was fun... ");
            this.notify();
        }
    }

}

private synchronized void testingOneThreadEntry(Thread threadInside) {
    System.out.println(threadInside.getName() + " is in");
    System.out.println("Hey! I am inside and I am enjoying");
    try {
        threadInside.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

---

I am not able to start the ThreadTest instances.

I expect that ThreadTest's run method be executed as soon as the line `th.start();` is executed, the one inside main method.

When I run the program, I see niether my system.out nor any exception.

I debugged also, but could see loop runs 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just started a `Thread`, not a `ThreadTest`.  `Thread`'s `run()` method does nothing.  Instead, create and `start()` a `ThreadTest`.

```
for(ThreadTest th : threads) {
   th = new ThreadTest(Integer.toString(i++));
   th.start();
}
```

You'll also need a one-arg constructor in your `ThreadTest` class that will take the `String` you're passing to it.

```
public ThreadTest(String msg){
    super(msg);
}
```

You'll also need to make the `ThreadTest` class `static` so you can access that nested class from the `static` `main` method.

```
static class ThreadTest extends Thread {
```

However, you'll wind up will all `Thread`s waiting.  As written, this code will call `wait` inside every `Thread`, but it will never get to `notify`.  The `notify` method must be called on the `Thread` to be notified, from another `Thread`.  If it's `wait`ing, then it can never notify itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have array of ThreadTest (thread) class which is not used.

I assume you wanted this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadTest[] threads = new ThreadTest[10];
    int i = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
        threads[i] = new ThreadTest();
        threads[i].start();
    }
}
```